# Visualizing 3D Lissajous curves

Tags: computational-physics, oscillators, superposition, software

[Lissajous figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve) are generally 2 dimensional, i.e. X and Y. But if an oscillation along a third axis Z (normal on the XY plane) is introduced, how would the resulting path look like? is there any website or simulator that can visualise (preferably rotate the plot on various angle) so that I can get an idea of what they will look like?

Comment: python + numpy + matplotlib.

Comment: i dont know any of the 3 @JEB

Comment: easy to learn. you can make your own rotatable 3D figures: today.

Comment: this is not exactly a software recommendation question. i want to know how does the curves look like

Comment: i will try them in next few weeks. Does they run on windows

Comment: You can try the website wolframalpha.com if you're interested in a quick way to visualize these. You can try a simple query like: x(t)=cos(t),y(t)=sin(t),z(t)=cos(2t) plot3d . It is limited in the sense that you can't rotate the figures but if you're just interested in the shape it should suffice

Comment: You can also try the software Geogebra, which has an easy to use interface and it supports 3D plotting as well. You can use a query like: X(t)=(cos(t),sin(t),cos(2t))

Comment: Geogebra is Awesome!!!! but I know very little about it. I use it to geometric construction. Would be great to see 3D things in geogebra. if I succeed i will post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the theoretical side. Like in the 2D case, the composition of simple harmonic motion on three independent axes corresponds to a closed curve in three dimensions if the ratios of the three frequencies are rational numbers, while it becomes an open, dense curve in a parallelepiped if frequencies are incommensurate.

In Physics, one may find different examples of such a motion. Probably the simplest and most direct realization is a mass attached to three pairs of opposite springs in orthogonal directions.

To visualize the trajectories, there are many possibilities. Probably one of the simplest applications (although very powerful) is [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/).

As an example of its usage for the present purpose, the following commands

```
   x(t)=a*sin(t)
   y(t)=b*sin(n*t+phi)
   z(t)=c*sin(m*t+psi)
   a=1
   b=1
   c=1
   phi=pi/4
   psi=pi/2
   m=5
   n=3
   set parametric   # set parametric representation for curves
   set sample 1000    #  number of points the function is sampled
   splot [t=0:2*pi]x(t),y(t),z(t)
   do for [i=1:360] {
   ang=30+i
   set view 60, ang%360, 1, 1
   replot
   }
```

produce an animation like the following.

[image]

Notice that even the simpler command

```
splot [t=0:2*pi]x(t),y(t),z(t)
```

produces a plot that can be manually rotated by mouse movement.

Comment: Thank you for so much valuable answer

Answer (score 1):

Lissajous curves are a parametric curve where $x,\,y,\,z$ are sinusoidal functions. For instance,
$$\begin{cases}x(t) &= \alpha\sin(t) \\ y(t) &= \beta\sin(nt+\varphi) \\ z(t) &= \gamma\sin(mt+\psi)\end{cases}\tag{1}$$
where $n,\,m$ are rational. This can be easily modeled in any programming language and graphics package (Python + matplotlib, as was suggested in the comments, would work well, as would JavaScript with Chart.js or even C/C++ and gnuplot).

If you find learning a (new?) programming language daunting and just want to observe the curves, then there exists a model you can play with over at [Wolfram Demonstrations Project](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/3DLissajousFigures/), though the demo is limited with the parameters (i.e., you are restricted to $\alpha,\,\beta,\,\gamma\in(1,2)$, among others).

Comment: im failing to upvote you due to tech glitch. thank you so much i will try the response tomorrow

Comment: It's not exactly a technical glitch, voting up is a [privilege you gain](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) when you have received 15 points of reputation; your profile shows only 3 rep.